# Safely disable WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, security

I am considering to improve security of my Wordpress website, and in doing so have come across WP REST API being enabled by default (since WP 4.4 if I'm not mistaken).

**What is a safe way to disable it?**

By "safe" here I mean that it does not cause unexpected side-effects, e.g. does not break any other WP core functionality.

One possible approach would be to use `.htaccess` rewrite rules, but surprisingly I haven't found any 'official' instructions on doing so.

Any help or recommendation is greatly appreciated :)

**Update:**
3rd-party plugins is not the solution I am looking for. Although I'm aware there are plenty of them that solve the task, they include many extra features that slow down the website. I would hope there is a one-line solution to this problem without the overhead of an extra plugin.

**Update 2:**
Here is the official opinion of Wordpress: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#can-i-disable-the-rest-api

According to this, the Wordpress team wants future WP functionality to depend on the new REST API. This means there is no *guaranteed safe* way to disable the REST API.

Let's just hope there are enough security experts taking care of WP security.

**Update 3:**

A workaround is presented in WordPress API Handbook - you can [Require Authentication for All Reque​sts](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#require-authentication-for-all-requests)

This makes sure that anonymous access to your website's REST API is disabled, only authenticated requests will work.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From the author original question I've chosen option 2 that came from wordpress official recommendations(https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#can-i-disable-the-rest-api). So just put in your functions.php to let only logged in users use the rest api (but just cross check original link in case my code block is outdated ;) ):
**UPD(01-10-2021):**

```
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
    // If a previous authentication check was applied,
    // pass that result along without modification.
    if ( true === $result || is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
        return $result;
    }

    // No authentication has been performed yet.
    // Return an error if user is not logged in.
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return new WP_Error(
            'rest_not_logged_in',
            __( 'You are not currently logged in.' ),
            array( 'status' => 401 )
        );
    }

    // Our custom authentication check should have no effect
    // on logged-in requests
    return $result;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please test / confirm that this exact code works as expected? Then I'll accept your answer as the correct solution

Comment: @EricGopak Sure. I adopted that in my blog. If you are logged out and accessing https://{your-host}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{post_id} u'll get this error msg -> 

{
    "code": "rest_not_logged_in",
    "message": "You are not currently logged in.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
Otherwise u'll get proper json response with post data in it.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I'll take it as the correct answer then :)

Comment: @DzmitryHubin - Is there a way to limit the requests to a specific user? If yes how and what impact would this have to services reliant on the API e.g. WordPress' Site Health check, Gutenberg, etc? I posted a question on the WordPress forum (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/344989/restricting-access-to-wordpresss-rest-api-to-localhost?noredirect=1#comment506004_344989) so hopefully you may be able to assist

Comment: @DzmitryHubin the code was updated on WP side, maybe you should update your answer.

Comment: @8ctopus got u. I'm glad to but not involved in any WP development right now. Can u please help me with adjusted code snippet so I can update it ? ;) Thanks.

Comment: @DzmitryHubin sure, just follow the link to wordpress you gave in your original answer and take the code snippet from there.

Comment: @8ctopus done. Thanks for reminder and have a nice day bro!

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer disables all API calls from unauthenticated users, but nowadays lot of plugins are dependent on this API's functionality.

**Disabling all calls will lead to unexpected site behavior** which happened in my case also when I used this code.

For example, ContactForm7 makes use of this API for sending contact info to DB (I think) and for ReCaptcha validation.

I think it would be **better to disable some (default) endpoints for unauthenticated users** like this:

```
// Disable some endpoints for unauthenticated users
add_filter( 'rest_endpoints', 'disable_default_endpoints' );
function disable_default_endpoints( $endpoints ) {
    $endpoints_to_remove = array(
        '/oembed/1.0',
        '/wp/v2',
        '/wp/v2/media',
        '/wp/v2/types',
        '/wp/v2/statuses',
        '/wp/v2/taxonomies',
        '/wp/v2/tags',
        '/wp/v2/users',
        '/wp/v2/comments',
        '/wp/v2/settings',
        '/wp/v2/themes',
        '/wp/v2/blocks',
        '/wp/v2/oembed',
        '/wp/v2/posts',
        '/wp/v2/pages',
        '/wp/v2/block-renderer',
        '/wp/v2/search',
        '/wp/v2/categories'
    );

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        foreach ( $endpoints_to_remove as $rem_endpoint ) {
            // $base_endpoint = "/wp/v2/{$rem_endpoint}";
            foreach ( $endpoints as $maybe_endpoint => $object ) {
                if ( stripos( $maybe_endpoint, $rem_endpoint ) !== false ) {
                    unset( $endpoints[ $maybe_endpoint ] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $endpoints;
}
```

With this, the only endpoints now open are the ones installed by the plugins.

For complete list of endpoints active on your site, see `https://YOURSITE.com/wp-json/`

Feel free to edit `$endpoints_to_remove` array as per your requirement.

If you have custom post type, make sure to add those all to the list too.

In my case, **I also changed the default endpoint prefix** from `wp-json` to `mybrand-api`. This should act a deterrent for bots that were making thousands of brute-force requests.

Here is what I did:

```
// Custom rest api prefix (Make sure to go to Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks and press Save button to flush/rewrite url cache )
add_filter( 'rest_url_prefix', 'rest_api_url_prefix' );
function rest_api_url_prefix() {
    return 'mybrand-api';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I find this highly customizable and works like a charm.

Comment: This seems to disable the listed rest api endpoints for not logged in and logged in users. At least through browser requests.

Comment: Testing through nonce authentication seems to work as expected. So it's just cookie authentication that is ignored.

Comment: @Anand, this is super helpful although it's manual and each time there's a change to the custom post type, it has to be updated.

Comment: @Anand, what unexpected site behavior did you experience?

Comment: This is a cool solutions due to it's flexibilty

Answer (score 15):

You can disable it for requests other than localhost:

```
function restrict_rest_api_to_localhost() {
    $whitelist = [ '127.0.0.1', "::1" ];

    if( ! in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist ) ){
        die( 'REST API is disabled.' );
    }
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'restrict_rest_api_to_localhost', 0 );
```

Comment: @HarryBosh it shouldn't, since it's in functions.php

Comment: Only plugins and themes are immune - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/230716/how-to-preserve-php-modifications-while-upgrading-wordpress

Comment: @HarryBosh functions.php is part of the Theme - https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained

Comment: ok so your not talking about /wp-includes/functions.php guess that is clarified now...

Comment: @HarryBosh when someone references `functions.php` in wordpress they're almost always talking about the theme's functions.php

Comment: It's good but in my case I had to add `"fe80::1"` to whitelist as well.

Comment: @LucasBustamante - I am conscious that you posted this answer some time ago now. Hopefully you'll be able to assist. It appears that when the REST API is disabled and limited to only the local host, when I attempt to execute services such as WordPress' Site Health check it returns a message that it is't functioning as intended. I posted a question on the WordPress (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/344989/restricting-access-to-wordpresss-rest-api-to-localhost?noredirect=1#comment506004_344989) forum that seeks to gain further clarity on the topic further

Comment: can you tell the difference, making that check inside your suggested `rest_api_init` action  OR checking that inside the filter `rest_authentication_errors` (like accepted answer's author suggested) ? 
I just wanted to combine both codes into one, preferably in `rest_authentication_errors`

Comment: not a good idea as you may break functionality.

Answer (score 14):

Disabling REST API was not a bad idea, after all.
It actually opened a [huge hole in all websites](https://blog.sucuri.net/2017/02/content-injection-vulnerability-wordpress-rest-api.html)!

In wordpress 4.4 [there was a way](https://wp-mix.com/wordpress-disable-rest-api-header-links/)

Here, [I've found a possible solution with `.htaccess`](https://forum.ait-pro.com/forums/topic/wp-rest-api-block-json-requests-to-users-comments-routes/)  but should be carefully tested in combination with whatever else is in your `.htaccess` file (e.g., pretty-url rules added by wordpress itself):

```
# WP REST API BLOCK JSON REQUESTS 
# Block/Forbid Requests to: /wp-json/wp/
# WP REST API REQUEST METHODS: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*wp-json/wp/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

A very drastic method, is also to have a `404.html` webpage in your root and then add this line:

```
# WP REST API BLOCK JSON REQUESTS 
# Redirect to a 404.html (you may want to add a 404 header!) 
RewriteRule ^wp-json.*$ 404.html
```

Note that, unless you use a static page, i.e., **not involved with wordpress** functions, if you want to return a `404` error with an appropriate error page, this is a complete separate topic, with [a lot of issues when Wordpress is involved](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7592)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would be really nice if you could test it, before I accept your answer.
A question though: why would you want to trick bots? And which bots do you think are going to crawl `/wp-json`?

Comment: I mean, I've tested the second option and it works on my setup. The first does not, but I think there is some issue with other `.htaccess` rules I have

Comment: The  malicious bots, those that can automatically test for *errors* and *holes* in your WP installation.

Comment: In my opinion, malicious bots are not so easily fooled as by simple HTTP status code (they can easily check contents of server response). I would prioritize being honest with indexing bots (e.g. GoogleBot) so that it never actually indexes `/wp-json` even if it happens to have an incoming link. HTTP status code 404 fits well here, I think.

Comment: sure, makes sense. But I would add /wp-json to blocked robots.txt anyway

Comment: Actually, I added a comment about 404 errors, turns out that it's completely set-up dependant how you do achieve that (add a 404 header) in wordpress. No silver bullet ahead.

Comment: for nginx: `location ~ ^/wp-json/ { return 404; }`

Comment: you'll probably end up breaking something in WP by doing so. restricting REST api use to authenticated users sounds like a better option.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to disable **`Wordpress REST API`** completely use this code:

```
// Disable Wordpress REST API
remove_action( 'init', 'rest_api_init' );
remove_action( 'rest_api_init', 'rest_api_default_filters', 10 );
remove_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_initial_settings', 10 );
remove_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_initial_rest_routes', 99 );
remove_action( 'parse_request', 'rest_api_loaded' );
```

Comment: After adding this code I couldn't add a new Post from the backend.

Comment: this code disable wordpress reset api completely  include gutenberg api. so you can use classic editor or you should use @Dzmitry Hubin code to just limit reset api to logged in users or custom roles

Answer (score 1):

With the plugin "[Disable REST API](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/disable-json-api/)" you can select which APIs you want to enable, e.g. the contact form 7 API. See the plugin's settings (yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=disable_rest_api_settings)

Comment: It would be a good practice not to use a plugin for each small thing, that may be achieved with a small filter function or some lines in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('rest_enabled', '__return_false');
add_filter('rest_jsonp_enabled', '__return_false');
```

Comment: Did not work for me, although I also found this lines on other blogs.

Comment: It's for WordPress < 4.7

Answer (score 0):

There are several points you need to "turn off". Also, you might want to place some kind of notice to someone coming to that page...

Here is what I used (and was checked):

```
function itsme_disable_feed() {
    wp_die( __( 'No feed available, please visit the <a href="http://www.example.co.il">Example</a>!' ) );
}

add_action('do_feed', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2_comments', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom_comments', 'itsme_disable_feed', 1);
```

As per [wp_die() docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/):

> This function complements the die() PHP function. The difference is
> that HTML will be displayed to the user. It is recommended to use this
> function only when the execution should not continue any further. It
> is not recommended to call this function very often, and try to handle
> as many errors as possible silently or more gracefully.

Hope this helps.