# How do I protect individual wordpress urls from being attacked?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I am trying to secure my WordPress site from hackers - more specifically, individual non-content pages that appear to be getting more hits. I am using Siteground and installed WordPress a few months ago. Checking the website statistics I was taken aback by what I saw. I have briefly summarised the page hits below.

**https://  ...  /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php** --> this page has been viewed over 16k times each month. Considering my site has been live for only 2 months, contains no SEO, and no-one knows about its existence this is odd!

**https://  ...  /index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/users/** --> this page is giving away my usernames.

**https://  ...  /index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/pages** --> appears to display code from one of my main pages.

And a whole load of pages that appear very odd to be accessing:

https:// ... /index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies

https:// ... /index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/categories

https:// ... /index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/post_tag

https:// ... /index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/category

https:// ... /index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/tags

https:// ... /wp-admin/load-styles.php --> shows blank screen

There's a whole load more, some redirects to the WordPress login page and others show a blank screen. There's also some URLs that allow any user to download a *.woff file (whatever that is?!).

Point is, I thought WordPress would be secure enough to not let these pages appear visible and show details at the very least.

Is there anything I can do? As I pointed out, I'm using Siteground which doesn't use cPanel.

I thought the most difficult part of a blog site is the content creation and overall web design. I'm not sure now.

Any help and/or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably the most impactful thing you can do is to make sure the user that runs the web server process does not have write access to any of the files or directories it's serving.

Comment: Go through your themes + modules making sure they're all required, up to date and trust worthy.

Comment: Wordpress sites are notorious targets for probes and you will get hits on everything in your site almost constantly as they try to find an opening. FWIW I use Gerber security to watch over things and it does a pretty good job of keeping the bad guys at bay. You aren't going to stop the probing unless you don't use Wordpress.

Comment: Even if you don't use WordPress, your server will be probed for various vulnerabilities. Like phpmyadmin, other CMS files, or framework files that could be in your web root. Another example is not protecting the `.git` directory from within your web root path. There are lots of other techniques outside of WordPress that need to be implemented to harden the security of your site, like CORS policy, Anti-XSS, CSRF, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for accessing login pages, that's to be expected with a WordPress site - bots love them.
You should have a strong password and use a nonstandard username for your admin-rights accounts. Bots will always access the default page with default login credentials to try it out. You could go another step and move the login page, too, that will massively drop accesses to the real login page, there's a plugin for it if you aren't comfortable coding that yourself: [WPS Hide Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/).

As for the wp-json URLs, you can ensure they are requiring logins / disabled with answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41191655/1843510), such as a plugin that disables it: [Disable REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-json-api/).

Concerning the .woff files, those are just font files, either a bot scrapes over them or a user is accessing them to view the web page as it was designed; not a concern really.

WordPress has a decent article on additional things you can do to secure your website as well [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/).

Comment: Thank you everyone and thanks zbee. If anyone else is reading this and uses Siteground then you can protect individual URLs on your website by using Site Tools -> Security -> Protected URLs. You can then add a username/password. I noticed the page views have decreased substantially.